# Безопасное взаимодействие с базой данных с PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, redbeanphp

Eсть скрипт на PHP который должен взаимодействовать с базой данных mysql. Тут возник вопрос на счет приоритетов. Что лучше, быстрее, безопаснее всего использовать? приходится  выбирать из вариантов:

- PDO
- библиотека RedBean PHP(ORM)

последнее легче всего использовать и я больше склоняюсь к нему.

Comment: mysqli использовать вообще никогда не надо

Comment: вы вроде спрашиваете про безопасность, а вопрос задаете про ORM, который скорее удобство дает. по безопасности и там налажать можно люто.

Comment: @andreymal при чем тут `mysqli` и почему это его не надо использовать?

Comment: @teran он упоминался в первой версии поста. Не надо использовать, потому что слишком низкоуровневая штука, которая конечному программисту в 99% случаев не нужна при наличии того же PDO

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии, понял что PDO - верное решение.

Comment: @AidarAibekov ну ещё не факт, ORM может и лучше :) Но лично я просто не в курсе, как в php обстоят дела с ORM

Comment: Не забудьте отключить изменение структуры при использовании RedBean.

Comment: @svgrafov зачем, за что это отвечает?

Comment: запрет `alter/create` запросов мб

Comment: @andreymal ORM всяких предостаточно. другой вопрос что они зачастую встроены во фреймворки, которые могут быть и не нужны. и судя по вопросам на SO, редбин довольно малый функционал имеет.

Comment: @AidarAibekov https://redbeanphp.com/manual3_0/index.php?p=/manual3_0/freeze